# Using regex filter in Accumulo Proxy C# client

Tags: c#, regex, proxy, accumulo

**Functionality attempted:**
Query and retrieve rows matching a certain pattern.
E.g. for search criteria -  rowID like "Dining*"

(Accumulo 1.5, Proxy API - CSharp).

**Summary:**

> Unable to retrieve records back (fails at client.nextK..in the code
>   snippet below). I get an error that says -
>   "result   {nextK_result(Success: ,Ouch1: ,Ouch2:
>   ,Ouch3: AccumuloSecurityException(Msg:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on
>   server 192.168.1.44:9997))}"

I have pasted the log file content after the code snippet, below.

**Code snippet:**

```
List<String> artifactList = new List<String> ();

String rowRegex = rowID + "*";
String colfRegex = null;
String colqRegex = null;
String valueRegex = null;
String orFields = "false";

IteratorSetting iterSttng = new IteratorSetting();
iterSttng.Priority = 15;
iterSttng.Name = "rowIDRegexFilter";
iterSttng.IteratorClass="RegExFilter.class";

Dictionary<string, string> iterProperties = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
iterProperties.Add ("ROW_REGEX", rowRegex);
//iterProperties.Add ("COLF_REGEX", colfRegex);
//iterProperties.Add ("COLQ_REGEX", colqRegex);
//iterProperties.Add ("VALUE_REGEX", valueRegex);
//iterProperties.Add ("OR_FIELDS", orFields);

iterSttng.Properties=iterProperties;

List<IteratorSetting> listIterSttngs = new List<IteratorSetting> ();
listIterSttngs.Add (iterSttng);

THashSet<byte[]> Auths = new THashSet<byte[]>();
Auths.Add (GetBytes("Public"));

var scanOpts = new ScanOptions();

scanOpts.Authorizations=Auths;
scanOpts.Iterators=listIterSttngs;


try{
    String scannerInstance = client.createScanner(loginToken, tableName, scanOpts);

    var more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        var scan = client.nextK(scannerInstance, 10);
        more = scan.More;

        foreach (var entry in scan.Results)
        {
            artifactList.Add (GetString(entry.Key.Row));
        }
    }

    client.closeScanner(scannerInstance);
}catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine (e.StackTrace);
}
```

**Error in log file:**

> 2013-12-07 15:28:01,126 [tabletserver.TabletServer] INFO : Adding 1
>   logs for extent 1<< as alias 4 2013-12-07 15:29:36,256
>   [iterators.IteratorUtil] ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   RegExFilter.class 2013-12-07 15:29:36,257 [tabletserver.TabletServer]
>   WARN : exception while scanning tablet 7<< java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RegExFilter.class   at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.IteratorUtil.loadIterators(IteratorUtil.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.IteratorUtil.loadIterators(IteratorUtil.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.IteratorUtil.loadIterators(IteratorUtil.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.Tablet$ScanDataSource.createIterator(Tablet.java:2084)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.Tablet$ScanDataSource.iterator(Tablet.java:2022)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.system.SourceSwitchingIterator.seek(SourceSwitchingIterator.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.Tablet.nextBatch(Tablet.java:1737)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.Tablet.access$3200(Tablet.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.Tablet$Scanner.read(Tablet.java:1879)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler$NextBatchTask.run(TabletServer.java:945)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.trace.instrument.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:47)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.trace.instrument.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:34)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RegExFilter.class   at
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.VFSClassLoader.findClass(VFSClassLoader.java:175)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.vfs.AccumuloVFSClassLoader.loadClass(AccumuloVFSClassLoader.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.IteratorUtil.loadIterators(IteratorUtil.java:232)
>     ... 15 more 2013-12-07 15:29:36,260 [thrift.ProcessFunction] ERROR:
>   Internal error processing startScan java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RegExFilter.class

**Attempt:**
Saved RegExFilter.class to $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/ext
This did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accumulo needs to know the full class name to load it properly (package included).

Try using "org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.user.RegExFilter" instead of "RegExFilter.class" as there is no class with that name and package.

Also, you shouldn't have to put any extra classes in $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/ext as org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.user.RegExFilter is already contained in accumulo-core.jar and should be in $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib

Comment: And for anyone attempting this functionality in Java, here is a link-
http://affy.blogspot.com/2013/03/exampe-using-accumulos-regexfilter-class.html

Comment: And here's a sample in python - https://github.com/accumulo/pyaccumulo/blob/master/examples/regex_search.py